# How do I remap a mouse button to do basically the same thing as a prefix for a hotkey in autohotkey

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, logitech

I am rather new to AutoHotKey, so please bear with any idiocy on my part, but I am trying to use at least one of my two mouse buttons (I have a Logitech M570 trackball and am running Windows 10) to perform basically the same function as a prefix key. I just basically want another key that can function like ctrl, alt, windows, fn, etc. I have been attempting to do this on a hotkey-by-hotkey basis, as opposed to just remapping the key itself (I don't want to lose any of the existing shortcuts based on the other prefixes) but for some reason, it doesn't ever work. I don't know if it's something in my trackball settings, or if it's something in AutoHotKey. Here is an example of what I have been trying to do

```
XButton1 & a::Left
XButton1 & d::Right
XButton1 & w::Up
XButton1 & s::Down
```

Which is supposed to turn `a w s d` into the arrow keys while I hold `XButton1` down.
If anybody has any suggestions on how to resolve this, I would greatly appreciate it.

UPDATE: There is nothing at all wrong with my code. The problem is my trackball. Do not attempt to use a Logitech M570 with AutoHotKey, it is quite aggravating.

HOWEVER, as is noted in the accepted answer, this script will render the key used in the remap useless, so don't adapt this using your `LButton` instead of `XButton1`. See the aforementioned answer for a better way to accomplish the same goal.

Comment: Ty the [Send](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) command `XButton1 & a::Send {Left}`. See also [Custom Combinations](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#combo).

Comment: Your code works for me perfectly. Check that your mouse actually generates `XButton1` with `KeyHistory`. If it does check with a script that has only those 4 lines and when it's the only script running.

Comment: I tried both of those suggestions, but neither of them seemed to work for some reason. Both mouse buttons show up in `KeyHistory` but neither seem to behave well in `Custom Combinations`. I have gotten them to run just fine when the mouse button is the only key used when firing the hotkey (a.k.a. key remapping). Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: UPDATE: these suggestions work just fine so long as I am not using my Logitech M570 Trackball. I don't recommend buying it if you want to use AutoHotKey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what didn't work for you, but that code will capture every press of `XButton1`, which is something you might not want. This version should work just fine.

```
#If GetKeyState("LButton")
a::Left
d::Right
w::Up
s::Down
#If
```

Comment: Thanks, mate! This worked just fine, BUT only once I used a different mouse. I don't think the Logitech M570 plays nicely with AutoHotKey. For some reason, it would register `XButton1` as being released immediately even if I held it down, and even though it registered me holding down `LButton`, and even sent the hotkey, it didn't perform the function for some reason. I might see if my original code works with my other mouse . . .